# How to install EPSON l210 scanner

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, scanner, gimp

I am trying to install the Epson scanner driver... I have extracted the `tar.gz.` file but on `./configure` shows the error

```
checking for GIMP - version >= 1.0.0... checking for gimp-config... no
no
checking for XML... configure: error: Package requirements (libxml-2.0) were not met:

No package 'libxml-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables XML_CFLAGS and XML_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details."
```

Comment: Why do you extract some tar.gz? Drivers for this scanner are available in deb format at Epson site. And how is gimp related to the scanner driver?

Comment: Gimp has scanner support builtin, that might be why the scanner driver searches for gimp

Comment: mine is an epson l210 printer cum scanner... printer is working fine but however i am not able to trace any .deb file on epson site ... i have tried installing other packages that they avail but oof no use... pls paste the links if you find the .deb package ... tysm

Comment: They change it from providing deb files to a tar archive with an installation script.

Comment: Is your system 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: WHOPPPIE... thank you so much ... i have setup the scanner... its workings Thanks  Pilot6 and Galgalesh

Comment: Checking for gimp-config is quite outdated, though - someone who's relying on those drivers should tell Epson about this.

Comment: @Galgalesh scanner support is not built into GIMP, it is provided by a GIMP plug-in from xsane.

Answer (score 4):

To install the driver go to [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule).

Enter the scanner model into the search box and select Linux as OS.

Click on download button at the right of "scanner driver".

Accept the license.

Click on "Package Download Page".

Click on "Download" button for 32- or 64-bit deb package. I assume you have a 64-bit system.

Copy `iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz` to your home folder.

Run in terminal:

```
tar xaf iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz
cd iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

Try to scan with "Simple Scan".

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a driver of the Scanner Modell **Epson Styus DX3850**. The installation routine does not differ between printers and scanners, therefore this instruction works as well for printers.

The following procedure describes the scanner driver installation on **Ubuntu 16.10**:

**1.** Access Epsons' Website and **find the driver** for the specific device, in my case the Scanner **Epson Stylus DX3850**. Choose the the driver for the corresponding OS, Linux 32/64 Bit.

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

**2.** Switch to folder where the driver was downloaded. Extract the archive and run **install.sh** inside the archive folder:

> cd ~/Downloads/iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x86.deb
>
> tar xaf iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x86.deb.tar.gz
>
> cd iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x86.deb
>
> ./install.sh

Afterwards, three folders are present inside the main driver folder, named:
*plugins*, *data*, *core*. Each folder contains a separate package, that has to be installed.

The packages has to be installed in the following order:

- A: Data
- B: Core
- C: Plugins

**3.** **Install the packages**:
Change in terminal to each package folder and install them in the following order by following commands:

Data Package:

> cd ~/Downloads/iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x86.deb/data
>
> sudo dpkg --install iscan-data_1.39.0-1_all.deb

Core Package:

> cd ~/Downloads/iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x86.deb/core
>
> sudo dpkg --install iscan_2.30.3-1_i386.deb

Plugins Package:

> cd ~/Downloads/iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x86.deb/plugins
>
> sudo dpkg --install iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_i386.deb

Finally, the Scanner application can be found in the computers dash under the name **Simple Scan**.

Observation: The Scanner itself is not listed as a device in the system settings, as in the printers case.

Greets

Tom

Comment: This worked in 18.04 LTS, although it appeared under the name "Image Scan! for Linux x.xx.x"

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing this but still the scanner is not working. Now simple scan recognizes the scanner as "unknown model", but does not scann. Other programs such as Image Scan! for Linux and gscan2pdf say the device is busy.

Do you know how to fix that?