# cannot use scanner Epson V330 on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, scanner

My scanner is Epson Perfection V330. Can I use it on Ubuntu 18.04? Currently the system does not recognize the scanner though it is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can use this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724323/how-to-install-epson-l210-scanner)

Here you can see how to download and install the driver... and I think this is the link in the [epson page](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult)
where you can download the driver...

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

This is the page where to download the driver: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule (type: V330 and choose Linux) - once downloaded, extract it, move the resulting folder home, then open up a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type: iscan-perfection-v330-bundle-1.O.1.x64.deb/install.sh - you will be prompted for your password. Once installed, shutdown the computer, switch on the scanner and reboot. Normally, it will work with Simple Scan.

All I said previously was true for 14.04 - I tried with 18.04 afterwards... and it did not work at all.

I found the answer here: https://www.ryananddebi.com/2018/05/26/linux-fixing-the-epson-v33-perfection-scanner-issue-in-kubuntu-18-04/

Since the driver was already loaded, I started at second step and did exactly what they said. My scanner started immediatly running, without even rebooting.